# Different archivesBaseName of apk file depending on debug or release isn't applied as wanted

Tags: android, gradle, apk

I've tried to give different base names depending on debug or release mode when building my android app. But it never becomes as I expect and I can't figure out how to solve it.

I have a android-part in my gradle looking like this:

```
def applicationVersionCode() {
    return 14;
}

def applicationVersionName() {
    return "1.5";
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy' // fix for https://github.com/loopj/android-async-http/issues/830
    }

defaultConfig {
    applicationId defaultApplicationId
    versionCode applicationVersionCode()
    versionName applicationVersionName()

    project.ext.set("archivesBaseName", "AppName-" + applicationVersionName() + applicationVersionCode())

    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 17
}

buildTypes {
    debug {
        minifyEnabled false
        versionNameSuffix "." + applicationVersionCode() + "-SNAPSHOT"
        applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
    }

    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}
}
```

When building debug mode the app gets the name:

```
AppName-1.14-debug.apk
```

And when I add:

```
project.ext.set("archivesBaseName", "AppName-" + applicationVersionName() + applicationVersionCode())
```

it gets the name:

```
AppName-1.14-SNAPSHOT-debug.apk
```

but then the release build gets this name:

```
AppName-1.14-SNAPSHOT-release.apk
```

I would like the different names of the apk's to be:

```
AppName-1.14-SNAPSHOT.apk
AppName-1.14-release.apk
```

What am I missing?